# Can I report stolen iPhone if I just logged out of iCloud on that phone?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, find-my-iphone

I used to have a phone. It used to be password protected and locked.

However, I wanted to jailbreak that iphone and the iphone is safely at my house anyway.

One day a female friend saw that iPhone and ask if I am using it.

I said no. I want to jail break.

She said his friend can jail break. So I let her have it.

The next day she reports her wallet is stolen and the iPhone is there. I don't trust her.

I go to find myiphone and no device is listed

I forget if I logged out of icloud or not on that iPhone. However, find my iphone says that it cannot locate any of my phone but one device is online. I have no idea where is the online device and which one.

Another list none of my iPhone

[image]

I put them all on lost mode. Not sure if things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you just logged out of iCloud on your iPhone, Find My iPhone was most likely also turned off, so it won't be of any help to you. However, if you *didn't* logout of iCloud, and the device is just offline, anything you set in Find My iPhone will be applied the next time your phone connects to a network.

Meanwhile, [Apple suggests to](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201472):

> Report your lost or stolen device to local law enforcement. Law enforcement might request the serial number of your device. Find your device serial number.
>
> Report your lost or stolen device to your wireless carrier. Your carrier can disable the account, preventing phone calls, texts, and data use.

Good luck.

Comment: I got the phone back.

Comment: @JimThio nice! You might want to mark my answer as accepted, or provide your own answer/a comment in your question to help others with a similar problem!